# I use the value a, b, c, d to derive the value of e. How can I set a, b, c, d to four decimal places whereas e to one decimal place?

Tags: c++, decimal, precision, iomanip

The code below is to display the value of a,b,c,d to four decimal places and the value of e to one decimal place. However, when I run the function, all five variables are in one decimal place. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Record{
    int year;
    string name;
    string team;
    double completions, attempts, yards, touchdowns, interceptions, e;
};

void passerRate ()
{
    double a, b, c, d, e;

    //quarterbacks is a vector of struct 
    for (int i = 0; i < quarterbacks.size(); i++){
    Record player = quarterbacks[i];
    a = (player.completions / player.attempts - 0.3) * 5;
    b = (player.yards / player.attempts - 3) * 0.25;
    c = (player.touchdowns / player.attempts) * 20;
    d = 2.375 - (player.interceptions / player.attempts * 25);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(4); // I want to set the precision of a,b,c,d to four decimal places 

    e = (a + b + c + d) / 6 * 100;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1); //I want to set the precision of e to one decimal place
    quarterbacks[i].e = e;  
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: How are you printing your variables? Show your code.

Comment: It is hard to understand what the question is. Is it that you want to print a,b,c,d upto 4 decimal places and e only till one ?
Also, e == (a + b + c + d)/6 * 100, does not set the computed value to e but instead performs a check if e is equal to it. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Also, what is fixed here ? Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking a question.

Comment: You can't. Floating-point variables don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and the two are incommensurable. If you want decimal places you have to use a decimal radix. More usually in non-money calculations you will retain all precision until the final display.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line `cout << setprecision(4) << fixed;` will *only* affect how decimal values are *displayed* to the standard output thereafter. Here's two solutions that should help you. If what you want is the numbers themselves to be rounded before they're used in other calculations, the following should work well for you:

```
double x = 1.23456;
double x1 = round(x); // x1 is x rounded to nearest whole number
double x2 = round(x * 10.0) / 10.0; // x2 is x rounded to nearest tenth
double x3 = round(x * 1000.0) / 1000.0; // x3 is x rounded nearest thousandth
```

Otherwise, you can set the standard output's precision between print statements, as follows:

```
cout << setprecision(4) << fixed; // cout will now print 4 decimal places
cout << "a = " << a << endl;
cout << setprecision(1); // cout will now print 1 decimal place
cout << "e = " << e << endl;
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't want to cout the value of a,b,c,d,e.  I actually wanted to leave a,b,c,d to four decimal places when calculating e. After the value of e is derived, I want to displace it to one decimal place and save it into a vector of struct (e is one element of the struct). Can I do that?

Comment: This solution is much repeated over the years, but it doesn't actually work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java/12684082#12684082) for proof.

Comment: @EJP : you're quoting a Java answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the precision for a particular usage of `cout`.

```
// displays a to 4 decimal places  
cout << setprecision(4) << a;

// displays e to 1 decimal place
cout << setprecision(1) << e;
```

Aside, `e = = (a + b + c + d) / 6 * 100;` does not make any sense. I assume you meant to use a single `=`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean to use a single =. Don't I need to use fixed? And I actually don't want to print out a,b,c,d but just use them to derive the value of e at their four decimal places. After e is calculated, I want then to display e in its one decimal place. Can I do that?